# Date to XMLGregorianCalendar conversion giving wrong results

Tags: java, date, gregorian-calendar, date-conversion

I have a code snippet that will convert `Date` to `XMLGregorianCalendar`, but after seeing the results dates are different. Not sure why change in dates after conversions.

Code:

```
public void getDate() throws ParseException {

        Date current = null;
        String str = "1980-10-26";
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date current1 = format.parse(str);      
        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCalendar = null;
        xmlCalendar = Utility.convertDateToXMLGreCal(current1);     
        System.out.println("xmlCalendar: "+xmlCalendar);
        current = Utility.convertXMLGreClndrToDate(xmlCalendar);
        System.out.println("current1: "+current.toString());
    }



public static XMLGregorianCalendar convertDateToXMLGreCal(final Date date){

        TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        GregorianCalendar gregoClndr = new GregorianCalendar(zone);
        gregoClndr.setTime(date);
        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGreClndr = null;
        try {
            final DatatypeFactory dataTypeFactory = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
            xmlGreClndr = dataTypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregoClndr);

        } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {

        }
        return xmlGreClndr;
    }
```

*

Results:

```
xmlCalendar: 1980-10-25T18:30:00.000Z
current1: Sun Oct 26 00:00:00 IST 1980
```

I am expecting `xmlCalendar` as `1980-10-26T00:00:00.000Z`.

Can someone let me know how to do that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, but it looks to me that the date is 100% correct, just another timezone?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not specifying a time zone in your `DateFormat` - so the system default time zone is being used. The result is midnight in your local time zone (IST) but in the `XMLGregorianCalendar`, it's being rendered in UTC.

The simplest way to fix this is to specify UTC as the time zone in your `DateFormat`:

```
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

That way each date will be parsed as midnight on the start of that "UTC day" which sounds like it's what you were expecting.

Comment: I have set the time zone as UTC in convertDateToXmlGreCal method, thats the reason result is coming in UTC format.

Comment: @reddy1234: But you're *parsing* the date as if it's in local time, when you call `format.parse(str)`. (It doesn't help that you're calling out to two methods that you haven't shown, which means we can't hope to reproduce the problem...)

Comment: Added the two methods code in the question, can you please help me now.

Comment: @reddy1234: I've already told you what you should do - have you actually tried that?

Comment: @Jan, that worked. But the actual aproblem is I will be recieving the Date from other applications and it won't be in UTC format. how can I make sure to pass Date in UTC format to the convertDateToXMLGreCal method. In the above code i wrote JUnit to test so i have put date in String and parsed. But in real time I am recieving it from other application. Could you please let me know how to make sure to send Date as UTC fromat for that method.

Comment: @reddy1234: There's no such thing as a "Date in UTC format". A `Date` value is *just* an instant in time. It doesn't have any concept of a time zone or calendar system. (The `toString` method just displays it in your system local time zone.) If the `Date` that you're being passed is incorrect, you should fix that instead - possibly by making a similar change. At this point I don't think there's anything else we can do with the question you've actually asked...

Comment: @Jan, So in that case if I recieve Date as '1980-10-26' from the application and when i convert to XMLGregorianCalendar it gives '1980-10-25T18:30:00.000Z' this result. So no way to get result as '1980-10-26T00:00:00.000Z'. If there is any way could you please let me know.

Comment: @reddy1234: Firstly, please stop adding `@Jan` at the start of responses. My name is Jon, not Jan, and you don't need to add anything for me to receive a notification given that you're commenting on my answer. Now, you talk about receiving "Date as '1980-10-26'" - are you receiving a `Date` or a `String`? If you're receiving a `String` you should parse it using the UTC time zone, as I've said. If you're receiving a `Date` then you're not really receiving '1980-10-26', you're receiving a wrapper around a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch - apparently for 1980-10-25T18:30:00.000Z.